# Is there a way to know when an audio was recorded

Tags: audio, android-versions

I recently received an audio on whatsapp and I am pretty much sure that its not altered.Is there a way to know when was that audio recorded in the senders phone.

Edit:It is a voice call conversation.

Comment: No. Unless the name itself has a time stamp like in the case of recorded telephone calls, which by default are time stamped (though that can be changed)

Comment: Its actually a vooce call conversation

Comment: This is independent of Android, but you can try checking the metadata of the file (perhaps there's an Android app for this, but I don't know) and see if the created date is stored. Otherwise, there's no way.